How to deploy the posthog on Cetnos?
I want to deploy the posthog on the CentOS. But stuck at pip install hogql_parser. When I pip install hogql_parser, it shows me the below something like related about gcc version compatibility. My gcc version is 12 and I've also tired 14 but the result is similar instead of another grammar warning. So how install it on CentOS? I've read the CONTRIBUTING.md within hogsql_parser, it only guide on the MacOS. Does anyone have tried deploying on CentOS? the official guidance is base on the Debian Linux or Mac, I have no idea for fix this problem.
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I /home/disk1/posthog/hogql_parser/ -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -fPIC -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/antlr4-runtime/ -I/home/disk1/posthog/hogql_parser/ -I/home/disk1/posthog/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c HogQLLexer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/HogQLLexer.o -std=c++20
      In file included from /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/stdlib.h:25,
                       from /home/opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/c++/12.1.0/cstdlib:75,
                       from /home/opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/c++/12.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:69,
                       from /home/opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/c++/12.1.0/algorithm:61,
                       from /usr/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-common.h:8,
                       from /usr/include/antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h:10,
                       from HogQLLexer.h:7,
                       from HogQLLexer.cpp:5:
      /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:56:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
         56 | #if __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_BFP_EXT) || __GLIBC_USE (ISOC2X)
            |                 ^
      /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/bits/libc-header-start.h:73:17: error: missing binary operator before token "("
         73 | #if __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_FUNCS_EXT) || __GLIBC_USE (ISOC2X)
            |                 ^
      /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/stdlib.h:133:35: error: missing binary operator before token "("
        133 | #if __HAVE_FLOAT16 && __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT)
            |                                   ^
      /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/stdlib.h:139:35: error: missing binary operator before token "("
        139 | #if __HAVE_FLOAT32 && __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT)
            |                                   ^
      /opt/compiler/gcc-12/include/stdlib.h:145:35: error: missing binary operator before token "("
        145 | #if __HAVE_FLOAT64 && __GLIBC_USE (IEC_60559_TYPES_EXT)

